# Are Riemann normal coordinates one to one and why can't they be defined in the presence of torsion?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, geodesics

In order to define Riemann normal coordinates at any point $p$ on the manifold, we parameterise the neighbourhood of $p$ as follows. Say we need to assign a point $q$ close to $p$ a coordinate, we first choose a tetrad at the point $p$ and consider the geodesic passing emanating from $p$ and passing through $q$. We then re-scale the tangent vector to the geodesic at point $p$ such that the point $q$ is on the geodesic when the affine parameter $\lambda = 1$. We then define the coordinates of the point $q$ to be the components of the tangent vector in the basis of the tetrad we chose. But is there only one geodesic passing between point $p$ and $q$ up to a re-scaling of the affine parameter? If not, how does this map properly define coordinates?

In addition, what part of this construction fails in the presence of torsion? It seems to me that we can apply this procedure regardless if there is torsion or not.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem (trivially based on the inverse function theorem) states that, in a sufficiently small open neighbourhood $U$ of a point $p$ there is a unique geodesic segment that joins the said point with any other point $q\in U$. This happens  for the value $0$ of the parameter  at $p$ and the value $1$ at $q$. Finally, the map associating the initial vector of the said geodesic segment to the point $q$ turns out to be defined in an open neighbourhood $V\subset T_pM$ of the zero vector and the map is a diffeomorphism between $V$ and $U$.

The presence of torsion does not matter here. It is instead relevant when constructing *normal convex sets* which are more complex structures. They exist in absence of torsion.

Comment: So is it possible to make the metric at a point minkowski and the connection coefficients vanish even when there's torsion?

Comment: No, it  is a different property. In Riemannian coordinates centered at a point what vanishes at that point is the *symmetric part* of the connection coefficients. If there is a torsion tensor,  it cannot be canceled by a suitable choice of the coordinates, even at a given point.  If there is a torsion, the connection is not the Levi-Civita one and thus it does not make sense to discuss if the metric becomes the Minkowski one at the center of a Riemannian coordinate system...